# Custom sorting using Typescript/ javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following data:

```
Data = [
  { "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "schist"},
  { "rock": "basalt", "youngerThan": null},
  { "rock": "Picrite", "youngerThan": "granite"},
  { "rock": "schist", "youngerThan": "basalt"}
]
```

etc and I would like to get a sorted array for `rock` based on attribute `youngerThan`. Note that `youngerThan` can be undefined which means this rock is the **oldest** (at the bottom).

Thus what I want to obtain is the following list: (oldest to youngest)

basalt, schist, granite, picrite

youngest to oldest

picrite,granite, schist, basalt

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: So from the above statements, its clear that [granite < schist < basalt], [granite < Picrite]. When you need to compare schist and Picrite, whats the condition?

Comment: This will do three simple sort operations 1.youngerThan 2.null 3.same rock 
https://gist.github.com/ThomasPV/67c75b857e92cbed71084b2296e3aa9e

Comment: (P.V THOMAS) thanks your solution works the best, note: there is a typo in your input data as you repeated the same "rock" property twice which should not happen.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    // Case sensitivity
    var data = [ { "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "schist"},{ "rock": "schist", "youngerThan": "basalt"},{ "rock": "basalt" },{ "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "Picrite"}]

    data.sort((a,b) =>{
        if(!a.youngerThan || a.youngerThan < b.youngerThan){
         return -1
        }else if (!b.youngerThan || a.youngerThan > b.youngerThan){
          return 1
        }
        return 0
    })

    console.log(data);
```

```js
// Case insensitivity
var data = [ { "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "schist"},{ "rock": "schist", "youngerThan": "basalt"},{ "rock": "basalt" },{ "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "Picrite"}]

data.sort((a,b) =>{
    var nameA = a.youngerThan ? a.youngerThan.toUpperCase() : null ; // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.youngerThan ? b.youngerThan.toUpperCase() : null ; // ignore upper and lowercase
    if(!nameA || nameA < nameB){
     return -1;
    }else if (!nameB || nameA > nameB){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})

console.log(data);
```

Comment: you need the information between `a` and `b` if they are not direct connected.

Comment: Sorry @NinaScholz, I don't get the point. Given the array of the question, we can use the `youngerThan` property to make the comparison. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The sort function in javascript can take an optional comparator as an argument to sort in a defined order for complex objects like the one you have. I didn't understand fully what you wanted but something like this can be done. I mean you can modify this custom function here to sort the object according to your own preferences.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
function compare(obj1,obj2){
if(obj1.youngerThan === null)
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
}

var Data = [
{ "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "schist"},
{ "rock": "schist", "youngerThan": "basalt"},
{ "rock": "basalt", "youngerThan": null},
{ "rock": "granite", "youngerThan": "picrite"}
];

Data.sort(compare);

console.log(Data);
/*
[ { rock: 'basalt', youngerThan: null },
{ rock: 'granite', youngerThan: 'picrite' },
{ rock: 'schist', youngerThan: 'basalt' },
{ rock: 'granite', youngerThan: 'schist' } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to sort the data by the given relation with a tree and then get a sorted result by traversing the tree.

```js
var data = [{ rock: "granite", youngerThan: "schist" }, { rock: "basalt", youngerThan: null }, { rock: "Picrite", youngerThan: "granite" }, { rock: "schist", youngerThan: "basalt" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.rock] = { data: a, children: o[a.rock] && o[a.rock].children };
            if (a.youngerThan === root) {
                r.push(o[a.rock]);
            } else {
                o[a.youngerThan] = o[a.youngerThan] || {};
                o[a.youngerThan].children = o[a.youngerThan].children || [];
                o[a.youngerThan].children.push(o[a.rock]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, null),
    sorted = tree.reduce(function traverse(r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.data, (a.children || []).reduce(traverse, []));
    }, [])

console.log(sorted);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```